# Download Shortcut Malfunction on Dock

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, dock

Whenever I add the download shortcut to my dock and then click it, the dock area goes black and when it reappears it goes away. It basically looks like every time I click the download shortcut it kills the dock and removes the shortcut. Some helpful background info: I have been having this issue since I had to uninstall CDock with the installation of Mojave. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.